# Bar plot with error bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a box plot/stacked bar graph with error bars.

**output of dput(DF)**

```
`structure(list(Cell_Type = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("Fibroblast", "T cell", 
"Macrophage", "Tumor", "Islets of Langerhans", "Endothelial", 
"B cell"), class = "factor"), Condition = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("treated", 
"untreated"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(6051L, 1892L, 1133L, 
657L, 116L, 868L, 832L, 5331L, 3757L, 1802L, 835L, 287L, 704L, 
256L), Percent = c(52.3941466793662, 16.3823707680319, 9.8103731924842, 
5.68880422547407, 1.00441596675037, 7.51580223395965, 7.20408693393367, 
41.0962072155412, 28.9623805118717, 13.8914585260561, 6.43694110391613, 
2.21245760098674, 5.42707369719396, 1.97348134443417)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), groups = structure(list(
    Condition = structure(1:2, .Label = c("treated", "untreated"
    ), class = "factor"), .rows = list(1:7, 8:14)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))`
```

Gives me the following dataset.

```
       Var1      Var2 Freq
1   Fibroblast   treated 6051
2       T cell   treated 1892
3   Macrophage   treated 1133
4     Stellate   treated  893
5       Acinar   treated  148
6  Endothelial   treated  868
7   Fibroblast untreated 5331
8       T cell untreated 3757
9   Macrophage untreated 1802
10    Stellate untreated 1061
11      Acinar untreated 2786
12 Endothelial untreated  704

library(dplyr)
DF <- df %>% rename(Cell_Type = Var1, Condition = Var2) %>%
  group_by(Condition) %>% 
  mutate(Percent = Freq / sum(Freq)*100)

# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   Condition [2]
   Cell_Type   Condition  Freq Percent
   <fct>       <fct>     <int>   <dbl>
 1 Fibroblast  treated    6051   55.1 
 2 T cell      treated    1892   17.2 
 3 Macrophage  treated    1133   10.3 
 4 Stellate    treated     893    8.13
 5 Acinar      treated     148    1.35
 6 Endothelial treated     868    7.90
 7 Fibroblast  untreated  5331   34.5 
 8 T cell      untreated  3757   24.3 
 9 Macrophage  untreated  1802   11.7 
10 Stellate    untreated  1061    6.87
11 Acinar      untreated  2786   18.0 
12 Endothelial untreated   704    4.56
```

Calculated SD/Mean with this:

```
my_sum_1 <- DF %>%
    group_by(Cell_Type) %>%
    summarise( 
        n=n(),
        mean=mean(Freq),
        sd=sd(Freq)
    ) %>%
    mutate( se=sd/sqrt(n))  %>%
    mutate( ic=se * qt((1-0.05)/2 + .5, n-1))
```

Then plotted with this:

```
ggplot(my_sum_1) +
    geom_bar( aes(x=Cell_Type, y=mean), stat="identity", fill="forestgreen", alpha=0.5) +
    geom_errorbar( aes(x=Cell_Type, ymin=mean-ic, ymax=mean+ic), width=0.4, colour="orange", alpha=0.9, size=1.5) +
    ggtitle("Cell Types")
```

I want to plot based on condition. Not sure how I would do that. I tried the `fill` command but doesn't seem to work as the object is not found, I can't seem to add it back to the data set. How do I include the condition in the bar chart?

When I'm calculating sd, I think it's combining the cell type value into one, rather than taking it individually. How do I change that?

**dput(head(all@meta.data))**

```
structure(list(orig.ident = c("PDAC", "PDAC", "PDAC", "PDAC", 
"PDAC", "PDAC"), nCount_RNA = c(7945, 7616, 7849, 5499, 853, 
1039), nFeature_RNA = c(2497L, 2272L, 2303L, 2229L, 509L, 588L
), percent.mt = c(2.63058527375708, 3.7421218487395, 4.9433048796025, 
0.490998363338789, 0.234466588511137, 0.192492781520693), RNA_snn_res.0.5 = structure(c(5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 6L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
"17", "18", "19"), class = "factor"), seurat_clusters = structure(c(5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 6L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
"17", "18", "19"), class = "factor"), S.Score = c(0.0171539298241524, 
-0.00599651468836135, 0.011058574403656, -0.0424413740104151, 
0.03549521163095, -0.0243347616753686), G2M.Score = c(-0.0591387992008088, 
0.0253275642795205, -0.0512402869839816, -0.0239076248512967, 
-0.0263164126515597, -0.0339086517371782), Phase = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("G1", "G2M", "S"), class = "factor"), 
    old.ident = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Fibroblast", 
    "T Cell", "Endothelial", "Tumor", "Stellate", "Macrophage", 
    "B Cell", "Mast Cell", "Acinar", "Endocrine", "Exocrine"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("PDAC_AAACCCAGTCGGCTAC-1", 
"PDAC_AAACGAAGTCCAGGTC-1", "PDAC_AAAGAACAGCAAGTGC-1", "PDAC_AAAGAACAGGATGAGA-1", 
"PDAC_AAAGTGACATCCGTTC-1", "PDAC_AACAACCAGGAAGTAG-1"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is coming by the fact that when you calculate `mean`, `se`, ... you removed the `Condition` column, here is your `my_sum_1` results:

```r
# A tibble: 7 x 6
  Cell_Type                n  mean    sd    se     ic
  <fct>                <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Fibroblast               2 5691   509. 360    4574.
2 T cell                   2 2824. 1319. 932.  11849.
3 Macrophage               2 1468.  473. 334.   4250.
4 Tumor                    2  746   126.  89.0  1131.
5 Islets of Langerhans     2  202.  121.  85.5  1086.
6 Endothelial              2  786   116.  82    1042.
7 B cell                   2  544   407. 288    3659.
```

To calculate the `mean`, `sd`, ... from each cell types in each conditions, you need to group by `Cell_Type` and `Condition` by writing:

```r
my_sum_1 <- DF %>%
  group_by(Cell_Type, Condition) %>%
  summarise( 
    n=n(),
    mean=mean(Freq),
    sd=sd(Freq)
  ) %>%
  mutate( se=sd/sqrt(n))  %>%
  mutate( ic=se * qt((1-0.05)/2 + .5, n-1))
```

But now, your table looks like:

```r
# A tibble: 14 x 7
# Groups:   Cell_Type [7]
   Cell_Type            Condition     n  mean    sd    se    ic
   <fct>                <fct>     <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Fibroblast           treated       1  6051    NA    NA    NA
 2 Fibroblast           untreated     1  5331    NA    NA    NA
 3 T cell               treated       1  1892    NA    NA    NA
 4 T cell               untreated     1  3757    NA    NA    NA
 5 Macrophage           treated       1  1133    NA    NA    NA
 6 Macrophage           untreated     1  1802    NA    NA    NA
 7 Tumor                treated       1   657    NA    NA    NA
 8 Tumor                untreated     1   835    NA    NA    NA
 9 Islets of Langerhans treated       1   116    NA    NA    NA
10 Islets of Langerhans untreated     1   287    NA    NA    NA
11 Endothelial          treated       1   868    NA    NA    NA
12 Endothelial          untreated     1   704    NA    NA    NA
13 B cell               treated       1   832    NA    NA    NA
14 B cell               untreated     1   256    NA    NA    NA
```

Because in your initial dataset, you only have one value for each cell type in each condition, so you can calculate `sd`, `sem`. You need to first merge your replicates into your dataframe in order to be able to calculate your `sem`.

Then, you will be able to do:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(my_sum_1, aes(x=Cell_Type, y=mean, fill = Condition)) +
  geom_col(alpha=0.5) +
  geom_errorbar( aes(ymin=mean-ic, ymax=mean+ic), width=0.4, colour="orange", alpha=0.9, size=1.5) +
  ggtitle("Cell Types")
```

Hope it helps you to figure it out what is your issue with your current data.

Comment: How do I merge a dataframe? These aren't replicates though. For each cell type, I have two conditions.

Comment: If you made replicates of your experiment, you should have multiple tables similar to  `DF` (one for each replicate) with the count of each cell types per conditions. If so, you can merge all of them (take a look for function `?merge()` or `?full_join()` from `dplyr` (https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html)). If all of your tables have the same format and colnames, you can consider using `rbind` (and adding first a condition column to each table corresponding to the replicate number).

Comment: I uploaded the question with the dataset before I calculated the frequencies and percentages.

Comment: I don't think it changes anything. This table does not represent replicates right ? Do you have replicates for this experiment ? What I mean by replicates is that you run a scRNAseq several times on your biological samples, and you identify the percentage of cell types in each of this runs. How do you design your experiments ? Can you describe it a little bit ? (no need to know exact parameters, just what you are trying to do and what materials did you use at the beginning)

Comment: I run one sample on the 10x chromium box. This data set contains samples from treated and untreated patients. 15 treated and 16 untreated samples. I run all the raw files through Seurat.

Comment: I uploaded the metadata from Seurat.